# Android SplashScreen issue

Tags: screen, splash-screen

I using splash screen by applying theme to launcher activity. However, after android +12, it does not work. I googled, and found that I have to apply new google splashscreen API. I had implemented below steps :

- Add library reference to my build.gradle. >>  **implementation "androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0"**
- set my  **minSdkVersion 21**  , mandatory for splash screen to work
- Sync app ... **successful**
- Run App >> **get below error.** :   /Users/Makarem/Downloads/smartTable-master 2/gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/92ae6c048b8b436ddb2bab3ac0ed2431/jetified-core-splashscreen-1.0.0/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:3:5-9:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon' not found.

When I **perform above steps into new empty project,** **I can run app successfully** .
I have noticed that android is creating this folder "/Users/Makarem/Downloads/smartTable-master 2/" when I Sync my application. I do not know even why android studio/Mac is extracting gradle files into external folder. but the error , xml file is created during Gradle Sync.

Any thoughts to resolve this errpr ? Thanks..
NB :

- I know there are next steps to run splash screen, but current issue is stopping me to update my project. , but i can run into new empty project.
- values-31.xml content is :

> ```
> <style name="Theme.SplashScreen" parent="Base.Theme.SplashScreen.DayNight">
>     <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">?windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon</item>
>     <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">?windowSplashScreenBackground</item>
>     <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">
>         ?windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration
>     </item>
> </style>
> <style name="Theme.SplashScreen.IconBackground" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
>     <item name="android:windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor">
>         ?windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor
>     </item>
> </style> </resources>
> ```